# How can I select and delete the first row of my database?

Tags: python, mysql, database

This is my code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "raspberry", "cribdb")
curs=db.cursor()

curs.execute ("""INSERT INTO tbstatus values(NOT NULL, 'status')""")

db.commit()

number_of_rows= curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tbstatus")

if (number_of_rows <= 5):

    print(number_of_rows)
else:

    curs.execute("""SELECT * from tbstatus""")

    row1=curs.fetchone()

    db.commit()

    curs.execute("""Delete from tbstatus where id = 'row1'""")

    db.commit()

    print("\n Record Deleted successfully ")
```

It has no error but the delete function is not working. I just want to delete the first row of my database after it reach its maximum limit which is 5. What should I do? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use limit instead of ID

```
curs.execute("""DELETE FROM tbstatus order by id LIMIT 1""")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define the order of the records with `order by`. Then you can delete just one record with `limit 1`

```
Delete from tbstatus
order by id
limit 1
```